# How to prevent an iframe from running load event twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I googled the question and have tried many snippets; but got nothing. How to prevent an `iframe` from running load event twice?

**PAGE.HTML:** which is running at http://maindomain.com

```
<div class="regionBody">
    <iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" src="http://externaldomain.com/iframepage" height="215" style="border:none;width:100%;"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
$('.regionBody iframe').css({height: someCalculatedHeight});
</script>
```

**IFRAMEPAGE.HTML:** which is running at http://externaldomain.com

```
<div>some elements...</div>
<script src="frame-script.js"/>
```

**frame-script.js:**

```
var requestsTimeout = null;

function doRequests(callback) {
    clearTimeout(requestsTimeout);
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: some-url,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET'
    }).done(function (data) {
        // putting the result in frame's body
    }).complete(function () {
        clearTimeout(requestsTimeout);
        callback();
    });
}

function startRequests() {
    requestsTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('Doing requests...');
        doRequests(startRequests);
    }, 5000);
}

$(window).load(function () {
    console.log('IFrame loaded...');
    $(window).resize(function () {
        clearTimeout(requestsTimeout);
    });
    $(this).resize(function () {
        clearTimeout(requestsTimeout);
    });
    $('body').resize(function () {
        clearTimeout(requestsTimeout);
    });
    startRequests();
});
```

As you can see, I've tried any thing possible to prevent twice running the ajax requests. But still I can see in console which ajax calls are going twice in parallel. I mean I'm getting duplicate `Doing requests...` messages at same time, etc. Any suggestion please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your snippet seems over complicated, why are you trying to call request in timeout?

Comment: cause I want to repeat calls over the time

Comment: Ha ok, i missed the part you were recalling it in timeout callback: `doRequests(startRequests);`

Comment: The more I look at your question, the less I'm sure of what you're trying to achieve… Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: @Bigood I'm trying to make a cycle of ajax requests. But it seems the code is making to cycles.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do your request only once, you could use a global flag var to prevent multiple loads instead of timeouts :

```
var has_requested = false;     //The global flag

function doRequests(callback) {
    //Quit if there's a request in progress
    if(has_requested)
        return;

    has_requested = true;

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: some-url,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET'
    }).done(function (data) {
        // putting the result in frame's body
    }).complete(function () {
        callback();
    });
}

$(window).load(function () {
    //Don't forget to pass your callback here, I let it blank
    doRequests();
});
```

If you just want to avoid parallels request, you can reset the flag to false in the `.done()` and in `.complete()`, so it'll request only if the first request achieved.

#### Edit

If you want to repeat it over time, use `setInterval` :

```
$(window).load(function () {
    //You'd better store the interval identifier to clear it afterwhile, 
    //if you think you'll need to.
    setInterval(doRequests,5000); 
});
```

Comment: The `has_requested` will be `false` in both load events. It seems there are tow instance of that variable! The `requestsTimeout` in my code was going to do same. But none of them (mine or yours) were helping. But thanks to try. Cheers

Comment: @Javad_Amiry Aren't you loading your script twice? You should double check that.

Comment: Nop ): I double-checked everything that I could think about including the point you mentioned. I'm completely confused.

Comment: To help further, I'd eventually need an access to your dev site…